# Why does my TYPO3/Extbase 6.0 form always redirect to the welcomeAction?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

In my TYPO3 / Extbase 6.0 extension, I created a `SermonController` with two actions: `welcomeAction`and `submitAction`. In my `welcomeAction`, I'm creating a form using the following code:

```
<f:form enctype="multipart/form-data" Controller="Sermon" action="submitAction" method="post">
...
</f:form>
```

However, when I sumbit the form, I'm always back at the `welcomeAction`. Looking at the HTML source, I can't see where the action parameter is passed. TYPO3 creates something like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="sermon.html">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="tx_vmfdssermons_sermons[__referrer][@extension]" value="ExtensionName" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_vmfdssermons_sermons[__referrer][@vendor]" value="TYPO3" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_vmfdssermons_sermons[__referrer][@controller]" value="Sermon" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_vmfdssermons_sermons[__referrer][@action]" value="welcome" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_vmfdssermons_sermons[__referrer][arguments]" value="YTozOntzOjEwOiJjb250cm9sbGVyIjtzOjY6IlNlcm1vbiI7czo2OiJzZXJtb24iO3M6MzoiMjA4IjtzOjE0OiJhdWRpb3JlY29yZGluZyI7YTo1OntzOjQ6Im5hbWUiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjQ6InR5cGUiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjg6InRtcF9uYW1lIjtzOjA6IiI7czo1OiJlcnJvciI7aTo0O3M6NDoic2l6ZSI7aTowO319620254a4673760d044ba176b9925b7d33f8400bc" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_vmfdssermons_sermons[__trustedProperties]" value="a:2:{s:6:&quot;sermon&quot;;i:1;s:14:&quot;audiorecording&quot;;a:5:{s:4:&quot;name&quot;;i:1;s:4:&quot;type&quot;;i:1;s:8:&quot;tmp_name&quot;;i:1;s:5:&quot;error&quot;;i:1;s:4:&quot;size&quot;;i:1;}}fb8f3c052c5d4ded1adcf8f29303e5c68d2fa646" />
</div>
[...]
<button type="submit" name="" value="">Hochladen</button>
</form>
```

Both `welcomeAction` and `submitAction` are allowed as per `ext_localconf.php` and the FlexForm on the page.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure I'm overlooking something very simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the *Action from submitAction

```
<f:form enctype="multipart/form-data" Controller="Sermon" action="submit" method="post">
```